# Xcode10でプッシュ通知を実装したいが、require the provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature... と表示されビルドが失敗する。

Tags: swift, xcode

## 困っていること

[Reproの設定ページ](https://docs.repro.io/ja/dev/sdk/push-notification/setup-ios.html#provisioning-profile)を参考に、iOSアプリにプロビジョニングプロファイルを設定しようとしています。しかし、そもそもBuild SettingにProvisioning Profileが見当たりません。

[image: Build Setting]

結果として、プッシュ通知の設定をONにできず、ビルドが失敗してしまいます。

[image: require the provisioning profile with the Push Notifications feature]

## やったこと

XCode10からBuild Settingのメニュー構成やプロビジョニングプロファイルの設定方法がが変わったのかと思い、最新のやり方を検索しました。しかし、期待しているようなチュートリアルを見つけられませんでした。

## 環境

Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)
iOS 12.3.1

ご助言いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

プロビジョニングプロファイルがうまくアカウントにダウンロードされていなかったようです。

XCodeを再起動し、GeneralのSigningでAutomatically manage singingにチェックしたら利用できるようになりました。